# JavaFx with scenebuilder-which container or controls should I use for bus seat structure?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, scenebuilder

[Bus Seat Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aFRf.png)

I need to implement a bus structure which will be generated using number of row and column given, I used a scrollpan as the structure may grow. Each seat is needed to be selected by user. I know I have to generate a matrix, But how can I design the UI that will represent the matrix, each cell will be a button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) for this. You can create the columns as you like, add a style to it to fit your needs and perhaps add an empty column in the middle to achieve the same as in your picture. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) is also a good tutorial on the TableView.

You can also add columns to other columns. So in your example picture, you could add a "door" column which has a "left" and "right" column.